# dnn give HttpClient error 'The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel' on linkedin api v2 call in module

Tags: linkedin-api, dotnetnuke, dotnet-httpclient, dnn9

I am trying to integrate linkedin API v2 within dnn ( custome module) However  when try to get token via  httpclient request . It genrates error 
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

It works from mvc c# .net application but on  dnn  module it fails with above error.  Your kind  help in this regard would be highly appericiated

It works from mvc c# .net application but on  dnn  module it fails with above error.  Your kind  help in this regard would be highly appreciated. I have tried almost all solutions mentioned on stackoverflow but fail.

Using Dnn V9.3  with Framework 4.5  (4.6 also tried) DAL2 Module template. localhost  with http://localhost

```
 public async void SaveLinkedinTok(string code, string state, string error, string error_description)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/")
            };
            var requestUrl = $"oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri={AppConfig.Get("Linkedin.RedirectUrl")}&client_id={AppConfig.Get("Linkedin.ClientID")}&client_secret={AppConfig.Get("Linkedin.SecretKey")}";
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
            var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request
Inner Exception 
WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

var httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/")
};

...
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. I will check this and update. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me lot to sort the issue out. Have a nice day